# Why React raise: does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

Why I got this error? It is inside the `return` part.

```
12:26:46.325    Failed to compile.
12:26:46.326    ./pages/[lang]/event/[...eventId].tsx:205:23
12:26:46.326    Type error: Property 'enableSale' does not exist on type 'never'.
12:26:46.326      203 |               }}
12:26:46.326      204 |             >
12:26:46.326    > 205 |               {event!.enableSale && enableSaleSwitch
12:26:46.326          |                       ^
12:26:46.326      206 |                 ? translations?.tl485
12:26:46.326      207 |                 : translations?.tl486}
12:26:46.326      208 |               <a
12:26:46.358    Error: Command "next build --profile" exited with 1
```

Here `event` is declared:

```js
function Event(props: EventProps) {
  let event: EventOut | undefined = undefined;
```

Here declaration of `EventOut`:

```js
export type EventOut = {
  enableSale?: boolean;
```

This is where I initialize it:

```js
  const reload = (force: boolean) => {
    organizationId = getOrganizationIdFromEventId(eventId);
    let organization: OrganizationOut | undefined;
    if (organizationId) {
      organization = organizationList[organizationId];
      event = organization!.events[props.eventId];
    }
  };

  if (useClientSide() === true) {
    reload(false);
  }
```

Before `return` there is even a check. Failing line is in this return.

```js
  if (event && organizationId) {
    return (
```

It is not possible `event` get not real value.

So, what do you think what is wrong?

Also strange, that locally I can `yarn build`, only `Vercel` raise now this error.

Comment: Try changing `let event: EventOut | undefined = undefined;`   to `let event: EventOut | undefined;`

Comment: Please post your complete code for this component. These snippets aren't enough.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova your are right, this solved issue, but why? Would you explain why not initialize with `undefined` my variable?

Comment: It's just the way TS narrows types based on the last assignment (and calls to functions are not traced).

Comment: Just try to avoid any mutations and reassings